# Need help installing the MercurialEclipse plugin on an offline machine

Tags: eclipse-plugin, offline, mercurialeclipse

MercurialEclipse' [homepage](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/Home) has links to an [update site](http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable) and, indirectly, to [downloadable archives](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mercurialeclipse/downloads/list). I can't use the update site since my machine is not connected to the Internet, so I'm downloading the archive on a connected machine and copying it to the target machine.

But now - what do I do?

- Putting the JAR file (com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse_2.1.0.201304290948.jar ) in the 'dropins/' folder has no effect.
- Putting the JAR file in the 'plugins/' folder also has no effect
- Eclipse will not treat the archive as an update site (using Install New Software | Add)

So how do I install this thing?

Comment: I can't answer your question directly but please note the MercurialEclipse homepage is actually https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/

Comment: @johnpeb: Updated the question accordingly, still having trouble...

Answer (score 0):

These steps are untested but they should replicate the update site on your local file system:

1. Clone this repository: https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mercurialeclipse.wiki/
2. Download the stable plugin jar file from the downloads section and place it in update_site/stable/plugins
3. Edit update_site/stable/site.xml and remove all the <archive ..> elements.